# The long integer when using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following simple codes for the sum of two vectors.

However, I get the wrong results when I use NumPy.

[The results of the codes is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4VRm.png)

In [12]: %run -i test.py

The last 2 elements of the sum [7980015996L, 7992002000L]

The last 2 elements of the sum [-609918596 -597932592]

It's not a long integer, Why?

```
import numpy as np 
def numpysum(n):
  a = np.arange(n) ** 2 
  b = np.arange(n) ** 3 
  c = a + b

  return c

def pythonsum(n): 
  a = range(n) 
  b = range(n) 
  c = []

  for i in range(len(a)): 
      a[i] = i ** 2 
      b[i] = i ** 3 
      c.append(a[i] + b[i])

  return c

size = 2000

c = pythonsum(size)
print "The last 2 elements of the sum", c[-2:]
c = numpysum(size)
print "The last 2 elements of the sum", c[-2:]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain Python integers can grow arbitrarily large.  Numpy integers cannot; they are limited by the size of the data type.  If they get too big, they will wrap around and become negative.  It looks like your array dtype is probably int32, which overflows and results in negative results.  You can get the correct results in this case by using int64:

```
a = np.arange(n, dtype=np.int64) ** 2 
b = np.arange(n, dtype=np.int64) ** 3
```

However, it will still overflow eventually (if you make `size` larger).  You could also use `float64`, which allows even larger numbers, but then you will lose precision.

The cap on integer sizes is the price you pay for the speed numpy gives you.

Comment: Could also use `dtype=object`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: If you do that, there's not much reason to be using numpy for your computations.

Comment: You still get all the cool functionality. Like simply using that `** 3` on the array or `a + b` of two arrays. Or matrix multiplication as `a * b` etc. In pure Python that takes more code, which is more work to write and read. NumPy isn't just about execution speed.